# Identify topological errors using FME

Tags: shapefile, fme-form, topology, overlapping-features, snapping

I have one single shapefile with many features. There are three different topological errors that I want to be identified (only identified).

- Line A consists of many segments and some of segments overlap each other;
- Line 2,3 and 5 don't touch/snap exactly line A as it should be;
- Line 4 intersects line A and I want it split into two segments where it intersects with main line A.

[image]

Solution I tried:

[image]

"LineonLineOverlayer" and "Snapper" are working pretty good the only issue is that they both return not only overlaping respectively not touching segments but everything which means also the segments that do not have problems like 1 and 6! I have a bigger problem with "Intersector" which should be able to give me just line 4 which is not the case.

Any advice ?

Comment: I would identify line 4 by this criteria, line 4 Intersects another line while the end-points of line 4 do not Intersect the same line.

Answer (score 2):

There are several different questions here so it's hard to give one definitive answer but I would reccomend that you explore in detail the [TopologyBuilder](https://www.safe.com/transformers/topology-builder/) if you have not already. Look specifically at the "Advanced Parameters" because it provides a tolerance parameter that will probably be very useful in assessing several of your identified potential errors.